# How to reverse a name to a absolute url in django template?

Tags: django, templates, url

`{% url url_name %}` gives a relative name.

How can I do something like `{% absolute_url url_name %}` so that it returns url with base (including port if present)?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There are different solutions. Write your own templatetag and use  `HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri(location)`. But another way, and a bit hacky.

```
<a href="{{ request.scheme }}://{{ request.get_host }}{% url url_name %}">click here</a>
```

Edit: So I'm kinda confused this still gets me upvotes. I currently find this really hacky. Writing an own template tags has gotten a lot easier, so hereby the example for your own tag.

```py
from django import template
from django.urls import reverse

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def abs_url(context, view_name, *args, **kwargs):
    # Could add except for KeyError, if rendering the template 
    # without a request available.
    return context['request'].build_absolute_uri(
        reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    )

@register.filter
def as_abs_url(path, request):
    return request.build_absolute_uri(path)
```

Examples:

```
<a href='{% abs_url view_name obj.uuid %}'>

{% url view_name obj.uuid as view_url %}
<a href='{{ view_url|as_abs_url:request }}'>
```

Comment: Is there a way to include the protocol in this?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.scheme should help you with that problem.

Comment: @igo's answer below covers protocol as well

Comment: in 2020 there's not a better way?

Comment: @dangel, I totally agree with you. Was always wondering why this gets me so many upvotes. Updated answer with some possible answers.

Answer (score 20):

You can use the `build_absolute_uri()` method in the request object. In template use this as `request.build_absolute_uri`. This will create the absolute address including protocol, host and port.

Example:

```
 <a href="{{request.build_absolute_uri}}">click here</a>
```

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations (why it solve the issue, where was the mistake, etc...)

Comment: Accessing HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri() method in template. This will be simple and easy rather than {{ request.get_host }}{% url url_name %}

Comment: This only works if you're only interested in the path of the request, rather than an arbitrary `url_name`.

Comment: This does nothing to take care of named URL's

Comment: But it does give you the URL you want for the meta tag `og:url`.

Answer (score 11):

In template I use this to print absolute URL with protocol, host and port if present:

```
<a href="{{ request.scheme }}://{{ request.get_host }}{% url url_name %}">link</a>
```

In Python I use:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def do_something(request):
    link = "{}://{}{}".format(request.scheme, request.get_host(), reverse('url_name', args=(some_arg1,)))
```

Comment: As explained in my answer, in python could you use: `request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('url_name', args=(some_arg1,)))`

Comment: Is it possible to do this in templates?

Answer (score 0):

I use a custom tag `absurl` and the context processor `django.template.context_processors.request`. For instance:

Custom tag defined in `tenplatetags\mytags.py`:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def absurl(context, object):
    return context['request'].build_absolute_uri(object.get_absolute_url())
```

In `settings.py` ensure that you have the following:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'debug': DEBUG,
        'context_processors': [
            ...
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            ...
```

Then ensure the model has a `build_absolute_url`, e.g. for use by the admin area:

```
class ProductSelection(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    fixed_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, ...
    ...

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('myapp:selection', args=[self.slug])
```

The in the template itself use `absurl` to bind it altogether:

```
 {% load mytags %}
 ...
 <script type="application/ld+json">{
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "Product",
    "name": " {{selection.title}}",
    ...
    "offers": {
      "@type": "Offer",
      "priceCurrency": "GBP",
      "url": "{% absurl selection %}",      <--- look here
    } }
  </script>
```