# reverse('rest_framework:login', current_app=request.resolver_match.namespace) returns a weird path

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am working on a Django Rest Framework API. I was encountering an issue with my project where I keep getting the following error:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'login' with no arguments not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<version>[v1]+)/auth/login(?P<format>\\.[a-z0-9]+/?)\\Z', '(?P<version>[v1
]+)/auth/login/\\Z']
```

This error is very weird because in my urls.py class, I used the following pattern:

```
re_path(r'(?P<version>[v1]+)/auth/', include('rest_framework.urls'))
```

I looked at the file rest_framework/urls.py, this is the code inside it:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views
from django.urls import path

app_name = 'rest_framework'
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='rest_framework/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
```

So, I had no idea why the two patterns tried by the resolver were

1. '(?P[v1]+)/auth/login(?P\.[a-z0-9]+/?)\Z'
2. '(?P[v1]+)/auth/login/\Z'

since the path in rest_framework/urls.py is just 'login/', not 'login(?\.[a-z0-9]+/?\z' or the latter.

In order to replicate the error, I created a new simple DRF API:
views.py:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse



@api_view(['GET'])
def root(request, format=None):
  return Response({
    '/': reverse('root', request=request, format=None),
    'login': reverse('rest_framework:login', current_app=request.resolver_match.namespace),
  })
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import re_path, include
from demo.views import root

urlpatterns = [
      re_path(r'', root, name='root'),
      re_path(r'/auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),

]
```

When I sent a GET request to /, I got the following response:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "/": "http://18346ef2-eed4-4627-8911-7cd11a88eed2.id.repl.co/",
    "login": "/%2Fauth/login/"
}
```

The response is really weird. The first call to reverse() acted normal, but not the second one. I have no idea why, but I hope knowing why would help me at least figure out the reason behind the issue in my project.
Here is a link for the full demo on replit: https://replit.com/@HadilBader/demo#

Answer (score 0):

your path is

```
re_path(r'(?P<version>[v1]+)/auth/', include('rest_framework.urls'))
```

which needs one argument: `version`. Since you declare this as an argument, you need to pass it everywhere you need to reverse the url, something like:

```
reverse(
  'rest_framework:login',
  current_app=request.resolver_match.namespace,
  kwargs={'version': 'v1'}
)
```

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful. I have a question though.
 Calling reverse with a namespace does not return the fully qualified url. Do you know why?

Comment: yes, it works like that, you'll only get relative urls. You might need to create a function or a method somewhere to create the fully qualified url. check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19024159/how-to-reverse-a-name-to-a-absolute-url-in-django-template/34630561